# how to add http header to a pdf file using python?

Tags: python, http-headers

Hi is it possible to add a http header to a pdf file like Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=test.pdf in python, for now what i do is i send my pdf files to Amazons S3 by adding

```
--add-header=Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=test.pdf
```

but i would like to set this in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want to upload files to S3 using Python and set some extra headers along the way?

If so, you could use [simples3](http://sendapatch.se/projects/simples3/) library. Or some other similar library. I'll cover using `simples3`:

Follow the docs on how to instantiate a `S3Bucket` object. Once you have that, you can do:

```
bucket.put('path/to/your/pdf/object/on/s3',
           pdf_object_bytes,
           headers={'Content-Disposition': 'attachment;filename=test.pdf'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried writing to a file or parsing everything as a string?